# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when tls enabled in ingress nginx

Tags: ssl, django-rest-framework, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, django-cors-headers

I know that it seems that my question has a lot of answers already but bear with me.

I have a Django application running on k8s cluster with nginx ingress setup with letsencrypt staging tls certificate (the problem occurs with production certificate also).

I don't know if it matters but application uses `Basic Authentication` to authorize users which is setup with `drf` build-in authentication system.

I've setup CORS as follows:

```
### ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-routing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,X-CSRFToken"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - api.example.com
    secretName: app-ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: api.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-backend
              servicePort: 80
```

and in Django application:

```
### settings.py
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# I also tried setting:
# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
#     "https://example.com",
#     "https://www.example.com"
# ]
#

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    ],
}

...
```

But still when I send request from my frontend app I'm getting error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/somepath' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The weird thing is that when I disable tls in ingress the issue is gone. Tho with tls enabled, if I send request using postman or `curl` like that:

`curl -i -k -H "Authorization: Basic token" https://api.example.com/somepath`

I'm getting response with headers as expected:

```
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx/1.17.7
date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 18:58:50 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 9
vary: Accept, Origin
allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
x-frame-options: DENY
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,X-CSRFToken
```

I presume that headers are there because ingress itself added them (?)

I'm pretty new to whole devops world so I would appreciate any tip on where to look or what to check. Most of answers to this questions suggests to properly set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` and/or `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` which I already tried.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you ran into is not related to configuration. Bottom line is that you try to send requests across different subdomains (which CORS is preventing). You need either set
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin` to `"https://api.example.com"`
or serve API from the same domain - eg. `https://example.com/api`.